# Django table does not exist

Tags: django

I have a app in Django called webshopCatalog with the models.py. It is all in a development server, and I have previously dropped the mysql database followed by creating a new one since I was experimenting. The problem is, when I try to create a product now I get an error saying that the table does not exists (see the full error log when I click on the product link from admin). I have tried with `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it doesn't solve the problem.

I also tried to comment out the model followed by making a `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate --fake` and hereafter uncomment the model followed by repeating the steps without `--fake`, still it doesn't solve the problem.

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
from django.urls import reverse

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    allergic_note = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True) #Used for campaign products to show how many items there is left
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=0, default=0.00)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_deliverable = models.BooleanField(default = True) 
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'productImages')
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="comma delimited keywords text for SEO")
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="SEO description content")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique = True,
    help_text="Unique text for url created from name")
    printToKitchenName = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True,
    help_text= "Appears on receipt printer when printing to kitchen")
    printToKitchen = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("webshopCatalog-product", args=(self.slug,))
```

With the forms.py

```
from django import forms
from webshopCatalog.models import Product

class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']

    def clean_price(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['price'] < 0: #We allow 0 to be included in case we want to give out free products
            raise forms.ValidationError('Price cannot be negative value')
        return self.cleaned_data['price']
```

and admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

```
# Register your models here.
from webshopCatalog.models import Product #Category
from webshopCatalog.forms import ProductAdminForm

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm
    
    #How the admin site will list products
    list_display = ('name', 'price', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_display_links = ('name',)
    list_per_page = 50
    ordering =['-name']
    search_fields = ['name', 'description', 'meta_keywords', 'meta_description']
    exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

    #Sets up slug to be generated from product name
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug' : ('name',)}

#Registers the product model with the admin interface
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

The error I received when clicking on the product from the admin

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 17, 2022 - 22:47:06
Django version 3.2.12, using settings 'website.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[17/Mar/2022 22:48:40] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7433
Internal Server Error: /admin/webshopCatalog/product/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'hiddendimsum_web_db.webshopcatalog_product' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1697, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 749, in get_changelist_instance
    sortable_by,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
    return c()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 519, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 504, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'hiddendimsum_web_db.webshopcatalog_product' doesn't exist")
[17/Mar/2022 22:48:42] "GET /admin/webshopCatalog/product/ HTTP/1.1" 500 202172
```

Comment: you can try deleting the migrations folder and create a new folder with name "migrations" and it should contain "__init__".py file. Then run migrations command - "python manage.py makemigrations" , "python manage.py migrate".
Note: This will remove reset entire database, all data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by

```
python manage.py makemigrations webshopCatalog
python manage.py migrate
```